# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Shared counter variable between instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I have a Python Flask app running on Elastic Beanstalk with auto-scaling enabled. Now I would like to have a global counter variable that can be accessed and updated by all running instances in real-time.

I have looked at Redis with AWS ElastiCache but that seems overkill for my use-case since I have to store a single counter variable. I have also looked at the option of running Redis on one of the Beanstalk instances but that is not feasible because Beanstalk can shut off instances when down-scaling.

What is the best way to achieve this functionality? Any way to get away without using ElastiCache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using an **Amazon DynamoDB** table?

It has [Atomic Counters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters):

> You can use the `UpdateItem` operation to implement an **atomic counter**—a numeric attribute that is incremented, unconditionally, without interfering with other write requests. (All write requests are applied in the order in which they were received.) With an atomic counter, the updates are not idempotent. In other words, the numeric value will increment each time you call `UpdateItem`.
>
> You might use an atomic counter to keep track of the number of visitors to a website. In this case, your application would increment a numeric value, regardless of its current value.

Comment: Thanks. I was just looking into it! Will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: What would be the difference in terms of price and robustness between using ElastiCache and DynamoDB ?

Comment: @payne DynamoDB uses persistent storage and is a Regional service (running across multiple AZs), so it is highly resilient to failure. ElastiCache runs on Amazon EC2 instances "behind the scenes", so it is susceptible to potential failures. If you are just tracking a small number of counters, an ElastiCache cluster is overkill. DynamoDB is fully managed and you can just "use" it without deploying an infrastructure. ElastiCache is more suitable for caching frequently-accessed data without hitting a database.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein great answer, thank you! I've been trying to make up my mind about how to approach Atomic operations... It seems like I might get my team to move to DynamoDB instead. In any case, may I ask you to check out [my other question about ElastiCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305483/atomic-increment-with-spring-data-for-aws-elasticache-redis) ?